# Gatling2 Failing to use user session properly

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I hope someone  can point me into the right direction!
I try to run one scenario which has several steps that have to be executed in order and each with the same user session to work properly. The below code works fine with one user but fails if I use 2 or more users...
What am I doing wrong?

```
 val headers = Map(
Constants.TENANT_HEADER -> tenant
)
val httpConf = http
.baseURL(baseUrl)
.headers(headers)

val scen = scenario("Default Order Process Perf Test")
.exec(OAuth.getOAuthToken(clientId))
.exec(session => OAuth.createAuthHHeader(session, clientId))
.exec(RegisterCustomer.registerCustomer(customerMail, customerPassword, 
  tenant))
.exec(SSO.doLogin(clientId, customerMail, customerPassword, tenant))
.exec(session => OAuth.upDateAuthToken(session, clientId))
.exec(session => 

UpdateCustomerBillingAddr.prepareBillingAddrRequestBody(session))
.exec(UpdateCustomerBillingAddr.updateCustomerBillingAddr(tenant))
.exec(RegisterSepa.startRegisterProcess(tenant))
.exec(session => RegisterSepa.prepareRegisterRequestBody(session))
.exec(RegisterSepa.doRegisterSepa(tenant))

setUp(
 scen
  .inject(atOnceUsers(2))
  .protocols(httpConf))

object OAuth {

private val OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper()

def getOAuthToken(clientId: String) = {
val authCode = PropertyUtil.getAuthCode
val encryptedAuthCode = new 

Crypto().rsaServerKeyEncrypt(authCode)

http("oauthTokenRequest")
  .post("/oauth/token")
  .formParam("refresh_token", "")
  .formParam("code", encryptedAuthCode)
  .formParam("grant_type", "authorization_code")
  .formParam("client_id", clientId)
  .check(jsonPath("$").saveAs("oauthToken"))
  .check(status.is(200))
}

def createAuthHHeader(session: Session, clientId: String) = {
val tokenString = session.get("oauthToken").as[String]
val tokenDto = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(tokenString, 
classOf[TokenDto])
val session2 = session.set(Constants.TOKEN_DTO_KEY, tokenDto)

val authHeader = AuthCommons.createAuthHeader(tokenDto, 
clientId, new util.HashMap[String, String]())
session2.set(Constants.AUTH_HEADER_KEY, authHeader)
}

def upDateAuthToken(session: Session, clientId: String) = {
val ssoToken = session.get(Constants.SSO_TOKEN_KEY).as[String]
val oAuthDto = session.get(Constants.TOKEN_DTO_KEY).as[TokenDto]

val params = new util.HashMap[String, String]
params.put("sso_token", ssoToken)

val updatedAuthHeader = AuthCommons.createAuthHeader(oAuthDto, 
clientId, params)

session.set(Constants.AUTH_HEADER_KEY, updatedAuthHeader)
}
}

  def createAuthHHeader(session: Session, clientId: String) = {
val tokenString = session.get("oauthToken").as[String]
val tokenDto = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(tokenString, 
classOf[TokenDto])
val session2 = session.set(Constants.TOKEN_DTO_KEY, tokenDto)

val authHeader = AuthCommons.createAuthHeader(tokenDto, 
clientId, new util.HashMap[String, String]())
session2.set(Constants.AUTH_HEADER_KEY, authHeader)
}
```

So I did add the two methods that dont work along as expected. In the first part I try to fetch a token and store in the session via check(jsonPath("$").saveAs("oauthToken")) and in the second call I try to read that token with val tokenString = session.get("oauthToken").as[String] which fails with the exception saying that there is no entry for that key in the session...

Comment: Those are only methods calls, problem is somewhere in objects/methods you call in execs. Without any implementation no one can tell whats wrong. It would be also useful if you provide any error message from Gatling.

Comment: I added some more code and comments to explain what I do and explaining the error I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied it and removed/mocked any missing code references, switched to one of my apps auth url and it seems to work - at least 2 firsts steps.

One thing that seems weird is `jsonPath("$").saveAs("oauthToken")` which saves whole json (not single field) as attribute, is it really what you want to do? And are you sure that `getOAuthToken` is working properly?

You said that it works for 1 user but fails for 2. Aren't there any more errors? For debug I suggest changing logging level to `TRACE` or add `exec(session => {println(session); session})` before second step to verify if token is properly saved to session. I think that something is wrong with authorization request (or building that request) and somehow it fails or throws some exception. I would comment out all steps except 1st and focus on checking if that first request is properly executed and if it adds proper attribute to session.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will do some more debuggin tomorrow. I will let you know my findings when done!

Comment: I finally found my problem. I had global state like clientId and customerUID defined in my simulation class. Those values must be unique per user and are not defined and set within exec blocks/the users session.
Again, thanks a lot for you help mate!

Answer (score 0):

I think your brackets are not set correctly. Change them to this:

```
setUp( 
    scn.inject(atOnceUsers(2)) 
  ).protocols(httpConf)
```

Comment: Its still not working. The session is missing entries when running with several users